# How many times should I jump each day, before and after 9 PM, so I have the same number of jumps every day in both time zones (UTC and GMT -3)?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, puzzle, mathematical-modeling

I'm counting jumps. My jumps are timestamped, and I have the jump count on both UTC time zone and GMT -3 time zone (my time zone). The jump counts are:

| Day | UTC | GMT -3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 658 | 672 |
| Monday | 704 | 701 |
| Tuesday | 696 | 756 |
| Wednesday | 727 | 680 |
| Thursday | 738 | 740 |
| Friday | 688 | 669 |
| Saturday | 699 | 692 |

How many jumps should I jump each day on my time zone, before and after 9 PM (21h00), so I have the same number of jumps every day in both time zones (UTC and GMT -3)? How can I model this problem?

The number of jumps must be the same across all days of the week (ie. Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc, must all be "756" or "787", as long as they are all the same number). Also, I noticed that as the total sum of jumps must be the same on UTC and GMT -3, the numbers must also be the same on every cell of the table.

As an additional information implicit by the time zones, if I jump once on Sunday at 1 PM my time (4 PM UTC), my Sunday jump count will be 659 for UTC and 673 for GMT -3. If, on the other hand, I jump once on Sunday at 10 PM my time (1 AM Monday UTC), my jump count on Sunday will be 658 for UTC, 673 for GMT -3 and also my jump count on Monday will be 705 for UTC.

**Example**

Imagining a 3-day week, this:

| Day | UTC | GMT -3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 3 | 2 |
| Monday | 1 | 2 |
| Tuesday | 1 | 1 |

gets partially solved by this:

| Day | bef. 9 PM | aft. 9 PM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 0 | 1 |
| Monday | 0 | 0 |
| Tuesday | 0 | 0 |

making the table look like this:

| Day | UTC | GMT -3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 3 | 3 |
| Monday | 2 | 2 |
| Tuesday | 1 | 1 |

and from this point forward, the solution to equalize every number is trivial by adding jumps before 9 PM, which add the jump count for each day on both time zones:

| Day | bef. 9 PM | aft. 9 PM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 0 | 0 |
| Monday | 1 | 0 |
| Tuesday | 2 | 0 |

finally making the table:

| Day | bef. 9 PM | aft. 9 PM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 3 | 3 |
| Monday | 3 | 3 |
| Tuesday | 3 | 3 |

The final solution is the sum of each partial table:

| Day | bef. 9 PM | aft. 9 PM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 0 | 1 |
| Monday | 1 | 0 |
| Tuesday | 2 | 0 |

Comment: Why not just do all your jumps before 9 PM local time? Then the UTC and GMT-3 counts will be the same. Or does the puzzle require adding jumps to this particular table to get both columns the same? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I added a clarification on the same number thing, if it was not clear. I also added a complete example of how the table is expected to change and the expected answer.

Comment: Got it, the problem is to add jumps to an existing table so that not just both columns are the same, but moreover every cell is equal. Thanks for clarifying that. Can you jump after 9 pm on Saturday of the previous week? Otherwise I think your initial example is not solvable.

Comment: You can iterate through the week days to find an answer, but don't think of it like previous/next week kind of thing. Once the answer is found, you can make all the jumps in a single week. You can, however, take as many weeks as you would like.
I came up with one way to do it, I'll post the answer once I am done running some tests to a code I'm writing. Anyway, I think there are more strategies that can solve this problem.

Comment: Are you saying that jumps made on Saturday after 9 pm count for both the box in the lower right corner and the box in the upper left corner?

Comment: Yes. Jumps are counted +1 in all time zones, only different days, depending on the time the jump was made and time zone.
Reset everything to zero jumps in all days. If you jump 10 times in a row on a Monday 10 PM on your time zone, you will have 10 jumps, no matter the time zone you are accounting them in. You will have 10 jumps on Monday on your time zone, but will have 10 jumps on Tuesday on a time zone that is 3 hours earlier or more.

Comment: Sorry if the timestamp thing was misleading. I'm focusing on the statistics and want to even all days in both time zones. I mentioned the timestamp as my way to keep track of the time the jump was done, making sure it happened "in **a** Sunday", not a particular Sunday.

Comment: My apologies, you did say "yes" in response to my question about jumps on Saturday after 9 pm, which was a complete answer to my question. The part after "yes" didn't really explain the "yes", but it did not need to. I understand what your rules are for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by dividing the problem into two partial problems: calculate jumps done after 9 PM, to even the jump count on every day in both time zones (lines of the table); then jumps done before 9 PM, to even the jump count across all days.

As jumping before 9 PM equally changes the counter on both time zones, it is useless trying to find jumps considering jumps done at this time. Considering an initial state with 0 jumps in all days, jumps done after 9 PM are the only ones which can disturb the balance between time zones.

For the first part of the problem, the following algorithm solves the problem:

```
func(GMT_3,UTC):
1. initialize post9pm = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
2. while (GMT_3 != UTC):
3.   iterate through every day:
4.     if (GMT_3[day] > UTC[day])
4.       jump_diff = GMT_3[day] - UTC[day]
5.       post9pm[(day - 1)] = jump_diff
6.       UTC[(day - 1)] += jump_diff
7.       GMT_3[day] += jump_diff
8.       if (GMT_3 == UTC):
9.         break
```

It works by comparing the jump count on the current week day on the GMT -3 and UTC time zones. If there are more jumps on GMT -3, the difference is compensated by adding the jumps needed post 9 PM in the previous week day. It will count as jumps on the previous week day on GMT -3, but it will even the number of jumps in the current week day.

After both time zones have the same number of jumps in each week day (each line of the first table), we simply find the day with most jumps and add the difference to each week day by jumping that count before 9 PM.

**Example:**

The original problem is:

| Day | UTC | GMT -3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 658 | 672 |
| Monday | 704 | 701 |
| Tuesday | 696 | 756 |
| Wednesday | 727 | 680 |
| Thursday | 738 | 740 |
| Friday | 688 | 669 |
| Saturday | 699 | 692 |

After running the jump counts through the algorithm we get:

| Day | bef. 9 PM | aft. 9 PM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 0 | 57 |
| Monday | 0 | 60 |
| Tuesday | 0 | 0 |
| Wednesday | 0 | 47 |
| Thursday | 0 | 45 |
| Friday | 0 | 64 |
| Saturday | 0 | 71 |

and

| Day | UTC | GMT -3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 729 | 729 |
| Monday | 761 | 761 |
| Tuesday | 756 | 756 |
| Wednesday | 727 | 727 |
| Thursday | 785 | 785 |
| Friday | 733 | 733 |
| Saturday | 763 | 763 |

After that, we simply add jumps before 9 PM so all week days equal to the largest day count (Thursday in this example):

| Day | bef. 9 PM | aft. 9 PM | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 56 | 57 | 113 |
| Monday | 24 | 60 | 84 |
| Tuesday | 29 | 0 | 29 |
| Wednesday | 58 | 47 | 105 |
| Thursday | 0 | 45 | 45 |
| Friday | 52 | 64 | 116 |
| Saturday | 22 | 71 | 93 |

making a total of 545 additional jumps and:

| Day | UTC | GMT -3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 785 | 785 |
| Monday | 785 | 785 |
| Tuesday | 785 | 785 |
| Wednesday | 785 | 785 |
| Thursday | 785 | 785 |
| Friday | 785 | 785 |
| Saturday | 785 | 785 |